# Hex Addition Overflow detection

Tags: hex

I'm trying to detect whether a hex arithmetic results in overflow or not.

Using just 8 bit two's complement signed operation.

0xFF + 0x1

But first, I'm having trouble determining number is negative or positive in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 8):

In 2's complement, overflow occurs when the result is the wrong sign.

***Example:***

Two positives yield a negative result:

```
  01111111  (+127)  
+ 00000001  (+  1)  
-------------------
  10000000  (-128) <-- overflow (wrong sign)
```

Two negatives yield a positive result:

```
  11111111  (  -1)
+ 10000000  (-128)    
-------------------
  01111111  (+127) <-- overflow (wrong sign)
```

**Note:** overflow cannot occur if adding numbers with opposite signs.

```
  01111111  (+127)   
+ 10000000  (-128)    
-------------------
  11111111  (  -1)
```

Concerning the sign, the ***leftmost bit*** is the sign bit. **"0"** is positive
and **"1"** is negative.

***Example:***

```
       +------- sign bit
       |
       v
0xFF = 11111111 =   -1
0x80 = 10000000 = -128
0x01 = 00000001 =   +1
0x7F = 01111111 = +127
```

If the leftmost hexadecimal digit is `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, or `7`,
then it is positive. If the leftmost hexadecimal digit is `8`, `9`, `A`, `B`,
`C`, `D`, `E`, or `F`, then it is negative.